# Performance of LLVM-Compiler on native C code vs Python+Numba

Tags: python, performance, clang, llvm, numba

I recently did some tests on performance optimization in Python. One part was doing a benchmark on Monte-Carlo Pi calculation using SWIG and compile a library to import in Python. The other solution was using Numba. Now I totally wonder why the native C solution is worse than Numba even if LLVM compiler is used for both. So I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

Runtime on my Laptop

```
native C module: 7.09 s
Python+Numba:    2.75 s
```

Native C code

```
#include "swigtest.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float monte_carlo_pi(long nsamples)
{
    int accGlob=0;
    int accLoc=0;
    int i,ns;
    float x,y;
    float res;
    float iRMX=1.0/(float) RAND_MAX;
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for(i=0;i<nsamples;i++)
    {
      x = (float)rand()*iRMX;
      y = (float)rand()*iRMX;

      if((x*x + y*y) < 1.0) { acc += 1;}      
    }    
      
    res = 4.0 * (float) acc / (float) nsamples;
      
    printf("cres = %.5f\n",res);
    
    return res;
}
```

swigtest.i

```
%module swigtest

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "swigtest.h"
%}

float monte_carlo_pi(long nsamples);
```

Compiler call

```
clang.exe swigtest.c swigtest_wrap.c -Ofast -o _swigtest.pyd -I C:\python37\include -shared -L c:\python37\libs -g0 -mtune=intel -msse4.2 -mmmx
```

testswig.py

```
from swigtest import monte_carlo_pi
import time
import os

start = time.time()
   
pi = monte_carlo_pi(250000000)

print("pi: %.5f" % pi)
print("tm:",time.time()-start)
```

Python version with Numba

```
from numba import jit
import random
import time

start = time.time()

@jit(nopython=True,cache=True,fastmath=True)
def monte_carlo_pi(nsamples: int)-> float:
    acc:int = 0
    for i in range(nsamples):
        x:float = random.random()
        y:float = random.random()
        if (x * x + y * y) < 1.0: acc += 1
        
    return 4.0 * acc / nsamples
    
pi = monte_carlo_pi(250000000)

print("pi:",pi)
print("tm:",time.time()-start)
```

Comment: The question is, where the time is spent. I would not be surprised, this happens in random number generation. Using different random number generators will lead to different timings

Comment: I also thougth that rand might be the problem. On the other hand it is a function availabe for decades, so should be optimized as much as possible.

Comment: Did you run a profiler? Is rand optimized for speed or „randomness“?

Comment: No. I will check this, but nevertheless it can be expected that rand consumes the time. Is Numba working with another random generator? Because the other C code is obviously more or less optimal ...

Comment: Apart from the random number generator it would also make sense to compare with the same compiler settings (march=native, O3, Ofast) and using the same datatypes (double and int64). Have a look at `monte_carlo_pi.inspect_types()` there you can see which datatypes are used in the Numba implementation.

Comment: There is also (in this case only about 100ms) a mistake in the Numba timings. You are measuring compilation and runtime, instead of just the runtime. If you parallelize the function this gets very significant (0.8s instead of 0.4s) on my machine.

Comment: The timing I did was with the second run of Numba and cache=True. Furthermore I just tested a deterministic (equidistant grid) version of the C code. Time is now at 0.04 s!!! So the bottleneck is definitely rand().

Comment: @max9111: How did you parallelize? For me the parallel=True option said something like: ".. cannot parallelize ...".

Comment: `parallel=True`  and `for i in nb.prange(nsamples):` Automatic parallelization is generally only possible in very simple code and even than it is often beneficial to do it manually. But as said this increases the compilation time, which you included in your timings. Even loading the function from cache can take some time, especially if this is the first function you load from cache.

Comment: @max9111: Thank you. This was easier than using mpi4py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary up to now:

The rand() function seems to consume most of the time. Using a deterministic approach like this

```
...
ns     = (long) sqrt((double)nsamples)+1;
dx     = 1./sqrt((double)nsamples);
dy     = dx;
...
for(i=0;i<ns;i++)
          for(k=0;k<ns;k++)
          {
            x = i*dx;
            y = k*dy;

            if((x*x + y*y) < 1.0) { accLoc += 1;}      
          }  
...
```

instead of rand() results in an execution tim of only **0.04 s**! Obviously Numba uses another much more efficient random function.

Comment: Meanwhile I replaced rand() by the solution proposed here: https://lemire.me/blog/2019/03/19/the-fastest-conventional-random-number-generator-that-can-pass-big-crush/ and got an execution time of 0.59 s!